# Form Values Not fetching

Tags: php, forms, email

This is a contact form, when I click on submit button I am receiving the mail but form values are not fetched. I am unable to find the problem. Can someone help me?

here i include my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['fn'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['ln'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$sub = 'mail from xxxx.com';
$email_from = $subject;
$email_to = 'xxxx@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $sub, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
?>
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="send.php" method="post"">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fn" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ln" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address">
                </div>
                <div class="span7">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <input type="submit" >
            <p> </p>

        </form>
```

Comment: please post your form code as well so that we can see names of your input elements

Comment: Post the html form as well

Comment: Avoid using silent operator & check you error logs.

Comment: Please put your form code.it's necessary

Comment: Will be better if You look at post data(what sent form) by adding this line to your code: `printf('<textarea>%s</textarea>', print_r($_POST,1));`

Comment: I posted my html code

Comment: `$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));`   Where is logic, subject = email

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem with silly mistake....

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="send.php" method="post"">
```

in this line i can give  so changes is

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="send.php" method="post">
```